# Fail to connect robo 3t localhost; 27017 windows 10

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I have an issue with connecting or creating a local server.
It state that my computer wouldn't accept any connection to the server?

[error image statment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amaVM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because you haven't started up your MongoDB server.

If so, go to your terminal and type `mongod` to start your MongoDB server.

Answer (score 1):

change your bind_ip in /etc/mongod.conf from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 then restart the service